# Fix covering hovered table / hovering problem with table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with creating table. I need to create a table with some of cells with hover/tooltip event. For example when I point to the cell, I need to show one column table with  links, but when do this in that way I have problem with overlaping (I can't use links from first cell). For now I only tried to use CSS and HTML, but soltuion with JS is also accepted.

HTML:

```
<div class="ttip">
  <a class="foo">FOO</a>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><a href='bar'>Bar</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href='baz'>Baz</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="ttip">
  <a class="foo">FOO2</a>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><a href='bar2'>Bar2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href='baz2'>Baz2</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.ttip {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
}

.ttip>table {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: none;

}

.ttip>table td {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  padding: 2px;


}

.ttip:hover>table {
  display: table;

}
```

Live:

https://jsfiddle.net/uLm0gjcn/3/

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FOO2 is rendered after the FOO , meaning when its displayed, its technically below FOO2 text. To fix that you need to apply `z-index` in your css here in `.ttip>table`

```
.ttip>table {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This way, when the drop-down/tool-tip appears from FOO, it is rendered on top of FOO2.

Edit. Also, to make it not transparent, apply a `background-color` to css in `.ttip>table`. for example for a white background `background-color: white;`

Comment: ok, that solve problem with switching between cells, but the content of the hovered table is "transparent" and it is still unreadable

Comment: It is transparent because you do not apply any background color. to `.ttip>table` add a `background-color: yellow;`, or white if you want white, for it to not be transparent @tulptuiz